# OIDC Client: Creating two different logins for two different types of users

Tags: openid-connect

I am completely unfamiliar with how the OIDC client works, but I need to change this application from having one Log In link to two log in links, each link is for a different type of user, in other words, a user with two different roles.

I was informed that it's just as easy as creating those two links, but how does OIDC client know the difference between them if I am just replicating the same login link with the same login logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the way this works is for the app to simply run a code flow, so that the user authenticates at the authorization server (AS).

The AS can identify the user before choosing which authentiation method to use. Eg it can present a `username` screen, that prompts for an ID such as an email. Then it can look up the role and apply some logic.

After login the client can be issued with an access token containing a role claim. This can be sent to APIs which can also run branched logic based on the user's role.

Comment: does anything have to be done on my end, on the frontend for OIDC to know which role the user has?

Comment: No - but you need to ensure that the authorization server supports the above behavior. Eg confirm with people responsible for that component or consult the docs.